# Can a fey creature conjured by a Find Familiar spell be put to sleep with a Sleep spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, sleep

A fey creature conjured by a [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell relates somehow to the [racial trait "Fey Ancestry" of elves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/elf#ElfTraits), which says:

> You have advantage on saving throws against being charmed, and magic can't put you to sleep.

Does this hint that all fey creatures can't be put to sleep by magic?
And what effect does the animal form on the fey creature? A 'normal' beast can put to sleep by magic—does the animal form make the fey creature vulnerable to the *sleep* spell, because the racial trait will not pass into the beast body?

Adding to the confusion: A [sprite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sprite), a Tiny fey, has no trait saying that magic can't put it to sleep.

Answer (score 8):

#### No, the familiars have no such trait, and creature types have no rules of their own.

Having the Fey creature type doesn't automatically mean the familiar cannot be put to sleep. In fact, the *Monster Manual* even states that creature types have no rules of their own:

> The game includes the following monster types, which have no rules of their own.

The familiars would have to have a feature printed in their statblock that says they cannot be put to sleep, which none of them do, since being a Fey carries with it no rules of its own.